# PHP - Inserting blanks into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have clicked every link on here and I have yet to find anything that matches my problem.  Please keep in mind, this is for a school project and it must stay similar to how I have written it in order to `"count"`.

I'm hoping this is a simple syntax error caused by coding too long. If I format this wrong, please forgive me.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
// Connect to LOCAL or SERVER MySQL Database. Just change between local and server
    include('connect/local-connect.php');

// initialize and populate PHP variables from user-entered data

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $size = $_POST['size'];

//Build a MySQL statement to populate the database table

$query = "INSERT INTO shopping (email, size)
VALUES ('$email', '$size')";

// Run the query we just built
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Unable to write to database');

// Close the database connection
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

My table is named `"shopping"` and has 3 attributes:

1. ID (AUTO-INCREMENT PRIMARY)
2. email
3. size

I have copy/pasted this same code format from another .php page of mine that writes to another database table just fine. I can't understand why this won't work.

my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
project
sneaker1.htm -->

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Meta tag -->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex.nofollow" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Link tag for CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet/project.css" />

    <!-- Javascript tags -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/messages.js"></script>


    <!-- Web Page Title -->
    <title>Shoe Source Unlimited - Sneaker Sale</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">

                <img src="../images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />

        <p class="sh1">Shoe Source Unlimited</p>
        <p class="sh2">Your source for lightning sales of this season's hot shoes!</p>

    <p class="sh3">XXXXXX</p>
  </div>

    <div id="navbar">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="../homepage.htm">Home</a>                          
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Men's</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="../sneakers.htm">Sneakers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../loafers.htm">Loafers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../athletic.htm">Athletic</a></li>
                    </ul>                       
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Women's</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="../boots.htm">Boots</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../heels.htm">Heels</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../sandals.htm">Sandals</a>    </li>       
                    </ul>               
            </li>

           <li>
                <a href="../about.htm">About Us</a>         

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="../signup.htm">Sign Up</a>

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="../login.php">Log In</a>

            </li>

            </ul>   
        </div>



  <div id="external">

<p>

        <a href="https://twitter.com/XXXXXX" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">
            <img src="../images/twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" />
        </a>
</p>
        <p>Follow us on Twitter!</p>
    <br/>


<p>

        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXXX" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">
            <img src="../images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" />
        </a>
</p>
        <p>Like us on Facebook!</p>
    <br/>


    <a href="../em/projectem.htm">
    <img src="../images/email.jpg" alt="pinkemail"  />
    </a>

        <p> Send us an email!</p>   
</div>  

<div id="about">

    <p class="abouttitle">Red Sneaker with Black Laces</p>
    <p class="abouttitle"><img src="../images/shoes/sneaker1.jpg" alt="sneaker1" /></p>
    <p class="description">This low-top sneaker provides you with a comfortable wear with a stylish flare.  
    That red will surely catch some eyes!</p>

<p class="price">Price: $25.00 - tax included </p><br/><br/>    

    <!--Email -->
            <p class="size">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required
            title="Email: 6-59 characters, lowercase, valid email only!"
            pattern="[a-z0-9.-_]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}"
            maxlength="60"
            onfocus="emailmsg()" />
            </p>

    <!-- Pick a size -->

            <select name="size" id="size" required title="Select a size" >
            <option value="">Select a size...</option>
            <option value="sneaker1size1">Red and Black Mens 11</option>
            <option value="sneaker1size2">Red and Black Mens 12</option>
            </select>   




        <!-- change "get" to "post" and change to .php for database writing -->
<form id="joinform" action="../purchaseconfirm.php" method="post">
        <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" 
                value=" Buy Now! "/>
            <br/><br/>
        </p>        
    </div>




<div id="footer">

    <p>

        &copy;2014, XXXX

    </p>
</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is broken. Your input fields must be contained between opening and closing `<form>` tags. Your `<form>` tag is after your `<input>` fields.

Comment: @MikeW, That's right , Why don't you put that as answer ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you did not put your input under HTML form.

See code below for example:

```
    <!-- change "get" to "post" and change to .php for database writing -->
    <form id="joinform" action="../purchaseconfirm.php" method="post">
    <!--Email -->
        <p class="size">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required
        title="Email: 6-59 characters, lowercase, valid email only!"
        pattern="[a-z0-9.-_]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}"
        maxlength="60"
        onfocus="emailmsg()" />
        </p>

<!-- Pick a size -->

        <select name="size" id="size" required title="Select a size" >
        <option value="">Select a size...</option>
        <option value="sneaker1size1">Red and Black Mens 11</option>
        <option value="sneaker1size2">Red and Black Mens 12</option>
        </select>   




    <!-- change "get" to "post" and change to .php for database writing -->
    <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" 
            value=" Buy Now! "/>
        <br/><br/>
    </p>       
</form>
```

Also, it is better to put SQL query using parameterised query. In PHP, you can use [prepare statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). It is a good practice even to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Which means the input doesnt posted the entered value. The reason is `joinform` form  misplaced. In other words, input need to be inside the form tag. currently form tag started close to the `submit` button.

You can avoid these using `isset($_POST['email'])`...

it should be like,

```
        <!-- change "get" to "post" and change to .php for database writing -->
    <form id="joinform" action="../purchaseconfirm.php" method="post"> <--Form tag placment
    <div id="about">

        <p class="abouttitle">Red Sneaker with Black Laces</p>
        <p class="abouttitle"><img src="../images/shoes/sneaker1.jpg" alt="sneaker1" /></p>
        <p class="description">This low-top sneaker provides you with a comfortable wear with a stylish flare.  
        That red will surely catch some eyes!</p>

    <p class="price">Price: $25.00 - tax included </p><br/><br/>    

        <!--Email -->
            <p class="size">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required
            title="Email: 6-59 characters, lowercase, valid email only!"
            pattern="[a-z0-9.-_]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}"
            maxlength="60"
            onfocus="emailmsg()" />
            </p>

        <!-- Pick a size -->

            <select name="size" id="size" required title="Select a size" >
            <option value="">Select a size...</option>
            <option value="sneaker1size1">Red and Black Mens 11</option>
            <option value="sneaker1size2">Red and Black Mens 12</option>
            </select>  
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" 
            value=" Buy Now! "/>
            <br/><br/>
        </p>        
        </div>
    </form> <--End tag missed
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I didn't even realize that the form tag had to include everything. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here in your html code, you didn't put email and size variable inside the form element, that's why, $_POST['email'] and $_POST['size'] are blank.

You should move those elements inside :

```
<form id="joinform" action="../purchaseconfirm.php" method="post">
// add email and size element here
  <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" 
                value=" Buy Now! "/>
            <br/><br/>
        </p>        
</form>
```